# addition of two array elements and put it in third array in bash

Tags: arrays, shell

I am not getting any convenient code for :

I want to add three arrays into new one and add this new array value to a new column of a csv. My code so far:

```
sar -f -r > test.txt
sed -i 's/AM/ /g;s/PM/ /g' test.txt

IFS=$'\n'
arr1=($(cat test.txt | awk '{print $2}'| tail -n +3 | egrep -v 'kb'))
unset IFS

echo -e "${arr1[@]/%/$'\n'}"



sar -f -r > test1.txt
sed -i 's/AM/ /g;s/PM/ /g' test1.txt

IFS=$'\n'
arr2=($(cat test1.txt | awk '{print $5}'| tail -n +3 | egrep -v 'kb'))
unset IFS

echo -e "${arr2[@]/%/$'\n'}"


sar -f -r > test2.txt
sed -i 's/AM/ /g;s/PM/ /g' test2.txt

IFS=$'\n'
arr3=($(cat test2.txt | awk '{print $6}'| tail -n +3 | egrep -v 'kb'))
unset IFS

echo -e "${arr3[@]/%/$'\n'}"
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I want to add this three array value into one and put that value in a csv coloumb, i am not getting proper syntax to add this,this is my problem.

Comment: It is still not clear what you're trying to achieve. You have three arrays each filled with `n` integers. Do you either want to sum up the values `array4[i] = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]`, do you want to sum up the values of each array `array4[0] = sum(array1)` or do you want to concetenate the three arrays to one array holding `3n` values? Please edit your answer and make clear what you're trying to calculate. The easiest way to do this, is to give sample data and the expected output.

Comment: I want to sum up values in fourth array:array4[i] = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]...but array elements are command driven as you see..please provide me a suitable syntax for this.